# Issues with Modified Gaussian Fit

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a curve-fitting problem. I am measuring a system's response over a range of input values (both input and output values are scalar and real).

I change a particular parameter for the system between trials that results in different outputs for the same inputs.

This behavior is illustrated below:

[image]

I need to fit a model that essentially takes that parameter and x values and produce the observed y values as closely as possible.

I am trying to fit a Gaussian function as follows:

[image]

I am modeling $f_\alpha(c)$ as $a0 + a1*c$
I am modeling $f_\beta(c)$ as $b1 + b1*c$

Essentially make the peak and mean location shift as a function of the parameter c.

The problem is I am having convergence issues related to $f_\beta(c)$. If I just set the median to a constant I am able to estimate a0 and a1, but obviously the fit is poor. 
I am using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`

So my question is basically, is there a better way to tackle this problem? For e.g., a function that can model this better, better forms for $f_\alpha$; and $f_\beta$?

Sample data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QPjrpxaDnnj3pmqzjZgjJJLKWnQjLikc

Sample code here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=135P9euXYAoa9CR3hrLOg6ja_6XfGndDN

(Dataset is slightly different than what I have shown in the figure in the posting)

Two questions:
1. Is there a methodical way to make the guesses such that I am guaranteed to converge?
2. Are there better functions that I could use to approximate my observations?

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Just a note. The "mu" in the function is redundant since b1 accounts for it. So we could just assume "mu" to be 0

Comment: Do you have some output data we can play with?

Comment: I will post some data and code shortly

Comment: Sounds good to me, let us know!

Comment: looks somewhat skewed so not sure about the simple Gaussian.

Comment: Posted some data and sample code. Feedback and comments will be appreciated

Comment: Hmm, data is not what you show here, right? `y4` makes a big jump compared to the others.

Comment: Yes, different than the posted figure. Probably an error when creating the dataset - y4 shouldn't jump that much. I will fix it in a bit.  But y4 can be ignored and can consider just y0 - y3 to analyze this problem.  Thanks for looking into this

Comment: The number of coupling parameters between amplitude and position is far too high in my opinion. Is there a specific model of the coupling? I got good results with a much simpler model `a1*pos*np.exp(-(x-pos)**2/(2*sig**2)`.

Comment: @ChristianK. - thanks for your input. I see that your model gives a decent fit. However the peak position is what it is modeling against. My requirement is that there has to be a a dependency on c which is a system parameter (for e.g. temperature) that changes between these curves. I actually tried directly modeling the peak location as a function of c, but the results were poor.I need to model against the entire response instead of just the peak - hence I am resorting to this approach.

Comment: Changed the input dataset to fix some minor errors I had in it

Comment: @PythonRSAS I am not sure to understand what you are trying to do but I would suggest to use my simple model and then plot a1 in function of the external parameter you mention to find the relationship.